# How to use the slider in WPF to Zoom in and out of an image?

Tags: wpf, image

I am trying to use slider to control the Zoom in and Zoom out of any image.

I have written a code:

```
  private void image1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           if (!image1.IsMouseCaptured) return;
            var tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)
      image1.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
            Vector v = start - e.GetPosition(border1);
            tt.X = origin.X - v.X;
            tt.Y = origin.Y - v.Y;
        }
```

Here it is working fine. using mouse scroll. But I want to use the slider for the same functioning.

But unable to put the same behaviour like mouse scroll using slider. 
I am very new to WPF and its control, so any help with details is highly appreciated.

How can i implement the same finctionality of Zoom in - out using the slider?

Comment: To me your code doesn't look much like zooming, more like moving (panning) the image with the mouse position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research and coding I found that its a very simple application and very simple coding too, to Zoomin and Zoomout the image using a slider. what you need is to put a slider in the area of your choice. and put the following code.

```
private void slider1_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        TransformGroup transformGroup = (TransformGroup)image1.RenderTransform;
        ScaleTransform transform = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0];

        double zoom = e.NewValue; 
        transform.ScaleX = zoom;
        transform.ScaleY = zoom;
    }
```

Now I already have the code so that the image will Zoomin and Zoomin using the mousewheel.

```
    private void image1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        TransformGroup transformGroup = (TransformGroup)image1.RenderTransform;
        ScaleTransform transform = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0];

        double zoom = e.Delta > 0 ? .2 : -.2;
        transform.ScaleX += zoom;
        transform.ScaleY += zoom;

        slider1.Value += zoom; 
    }
```

Now when you put

```
   slider1.value += zoom;
```

Then changes in the mousewheel and in the changes in the slider change the zoom of the picture.

Remember the difference of implementation between mouse wheel and slider. In mouse wheel MouseWheelEventsArgs  "e" and e.Delte value is positive and negative depends on the mousewheel up or mousewheel down. But in Slider RoutedPropertyChangesEventsArgs value is positive or negative according to the sldier up and down. You don't need to specify here. Just

```
 zoom = e.NewValue;
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: Rather than change the zoom by the same value you might want to try `double zoom = e.Delta * .01D;` which will give a more dynamic response to the user's actions;

Answer (score 1):

You have to code a ScaleTransform in your code. This is a part of my code that do this, I don't put everything but it's a base for you.

For the slider, you have to bind the Zoom property to the Value of the Slider.

```
  private double m_dCurZoom = 1.0;
  private ScaleTransform m_transZoom;
  public ScaleTransform TransZoom
  {
     get { return m_transZoom; }
  }

  private TranslateTransform m_transPan;

  public double Zoom
  {
     get { return m_dCurZoom; }
     set
     {
        double oldzoom = m_dCurZoom;
        if (m_dCurZoom != value)
        {
           m_dCurZoom = value;
           OnPropertyChanged("Zoom");
           UpdateZoom(oldzoom);
        }
     }
  }

  public void UpdateZoom(double oldzoom)
  {
     // Are we visible?
     if (m_root == null)
        return;

     // Get parent
     FrameworkElement parent = GetRootParent();
     if (parent == null)
         return;

     // Center point of the window
     Point ptCenter = new Point(parent.RenderSize.Width / 2, parent.RenderSize.Height / 2);

     // Translate into canvas coordinates
     ptCenter = m_root.TranslatePoint(ptCenter, m_canvas);

     // Update the zoom
     m_transZoom.ScaleX = m_dCurZoom;
     m_transZoom.ScaleY = m_dCurZoom;
     m_transPan.X -= ptCenter.X * m_dCurZoom - ptCenter.X * oldzoom;
     m_transPan.Y -= ptCenter.Y * m_dCurZoom - ptCenter.Y * oldzoom;

     ResizeElementContents();

     OnPropertyChanged("Zoom");
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have certain questions,as I told you that I am very new to wpf and C sharp and I need to know a lot about how to do certain things for image  manupulation like tilting an image, rotate right left, Convert 2D to 3D. Zoom in out using mouse and using slider etc. Can you help me with proper guide, some links or e-books, that will be great. Can you please tell me what do you mean by "bind the Zoom property to the Value of the Slider"? and can you explain your code in short, if you really don't mind. I am new but really very very interested in wpf and C sharp

Comment: after a lot of search and coding I found that its a very simple application and very simple coding too, to Zoomin Zoomout the image using a slider.